# Cannot read property of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (Unsplash API)

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

having little problem. I was playing a bit with Unsplash API but can't move forward.
A was able to list a bunch of photos but I'm unable to make search working. Getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'small' of undefined at
>   XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (main.js:15)
>
> xhr.onload @ main.js:15
>
> load (async)
>
> loadImages @ main.js:7

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", loadImages);

function loadImages() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=office&client_id=15020f1f31839a088aff745486e7a469cd064761ff165c9d3d9f57de77d10348", true);

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(this.status == 200) {
            var images = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            var output = "";
            for(var i in images) {
                output +=
                '<div class="image">' +
                '<img src="'+images[i].urls.small+'">'
                '</div>';
            }

            document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = output;
            console.log(images);
        }

    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Basically, everything was working before changing that url (first link working well, second isn't). But the only difference is...

> https://api.unsplash.com/photos?client_id=
>
> https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=office&client_id=

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the response has a slightly different structure than you expect. You expect:

```
[
    {
        "urls": {
            "small": ...
            ...
        },
        ....
    },
    ...
]
```

However, there is an additional level at the root:

```
{  
    "total": 8519,
    "total_pages":852,
    "results": [
        {
            "urls": {
                "small": ...
                ...
            },
            ....
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

So instead of:

```
var images = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

you should write:

```
var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var images = response.results;
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. That was kinda stupid of me. Many thanks to you Codo.